# Angular data ist not defined

Tags: html, angular, typescript

simple question, I try to implement a login form and store it into the variable "data". But the console tells me ERROR ReferenceError: data is not defined.
But I did defined it. What did I do wrong?

Loginform.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loginform',
  templateUrl: './loginform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loginform.component.css']
})
export class LoginformComponent implements OnInit {
  data = {};
  constructor(private router:Router, private user:UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }



  formSubmit() {

    if(data.username == 'admin' && data.passwd == 'test'){
      user.setUserLoggedIn();
      this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    }
  };

}
```

loginform.component.html:

```
<div class="loginFlexCenter">
<div class="loginForm">
<h2> Studienverlaufsplan Login </h2>
<hr>
<form class="inputDiv" (ngSubmit)="formSubmit()">
    <div class="inputDiv">
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input class="txtInput" type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="data.username"><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="inputDiv">
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input class="txtInput" type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="data.passwd">
    </div>
    <div class="inputDivHalf">
        <input class="txtInput" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <input routerLink="/register" routerLinkActive="active" class="txtInput" type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if(this.data.username == 'admin' && this.data.passwd == 'test'){`

Comment: oh sure. Thanks alot. how could I not see this...

Comment: No problem, sometimes you just need a new set of eyes, happens to all of us ;)

Comment: It's also not a bad idea to define the properties of your object. `data = {username: '', passwd: ''}`